# How do I update an edge label in Gremlin?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am using gremlin query language for a graph database in cosmosDb. I have a set of edges named 'hasRole' and assigned to vertives of type 'employee'. I would like to change all the labels named 'hasRole' to 'isA'. How to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Element labels for both vertices and edges are immutable. You would need to `drop()` the element and then create a new one with a copy of the necessary properties. The recipe for [Moving an Edge](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#edge-move) might be helpful in this case.

Comment: a link in documentation for multi-label feature: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.4.12/reference/#_multi_label